# Disabling Liferay Webservice(s) using portal properties or Control Panel

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-dxp

I am using **Liferay DXP** for my portal application. I want to do following implementation using **Control Panel** or **Portal Properties**

1. Disable unused default/custom webservices.
2. Disable the access of API page (api/jsonws)

Whether above is possible using Portal Properties or control panel?

Any Reference/help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is 1) a configuration question, 2) asking for documentation. Those are two reasons to close an off topic question on Stackoverflow (see [help/on-topic]). If you bring it over to the Liferay forums: it will be on topic there (liferay.dev/forums)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#
# The property "jsonws.web.service.paths.excludes" denotes patterns for JSON
# web service action paths that are not allowed even if they match one of
# the patterns set in "jsonws.web.service.paths.includes".
#
# Env: LIFERAY_JSONWS_PERIOD_WEB_PERIOD_SERVICE_PERIOD_PATHS_PERIOD_EXCLUDES
#
jsonws.web.service.paths.excludes=\
    /user/update-password


#
# Set this property to true if JSON web services are discoverable through
# the API page.
#
# Env: LIFERAY_JSONWS_PERIOD_WEB_PERIOD_SERVICE_PERIOD_API_PERIOD_DISCOVERABLE
#
jsonws.web.service.api.discoverable=true
```

You can try above properties in portal-ext.properties.

For Reference visit. https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/portal.properties